# How to assign wchar_t string to CString member of user defined class?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

Here is the code as below that I used:

```
class A
{
public:
  CString abc;
  void fun1();
};

void A::fun1()
{
  wchar_t *Str = L"Stack Overflow";
  CString xyz = Str; // This works fine.
  abc = Str; // Whether this assignment is correct?
}

int main()
{
   A obj;
   obj.fun1();
   return 0;
}
```

While debugging I found that when breakpoint crosses the initialization code 
 `abc = Str`, I see in variable windows the string in `abc` is not updated with `"Stack Overflow"`.

Here xyz string is updated with "Stack Overflow" when I looked it into the debugger window.

Comment: Your code is correct. It's probably a debugger issue. Where exactly did you put your breakpoint? Put `TRACE("");` right after `abc = Str;` set the breakpoint on the line with `TRACE` and see if the debugger displays "Stack Overflow". BTW: you can simple write `abc = L"Stack Overflow";`.

Comment: I put the breakpoint just after abc = str; But the value of abc variable is not updated with string "Stack Overflow" in debugger windows. I used TRACE(" ") also, but still the debugger doesn't display "Stack Overflow".

Comment: Please report which IDE and version you use (probably some Visual Studio).

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2005.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line `return 0;` in `main` and report if the debugger dispays the expected value of `obj.abc`. Also replace `wchar_t *Str = L"Stack Overflow";` by `char *Str = "Stack Overflow";` and report your findings here.

Comment: Also add `printf("obj.abc = %s\n", obj.abc);` and report what is displayed.

Comment: Unicode is enabled in my Project. That's why I am trying  to assign wchar_t string in CString. BTW, it works when trying  to assign wchar_t string to CString member which is declared local in function fun1.

Comment: Please edit your question and show clearly the case that works. And add all other relevant informatino __in the question__.

Comment: @ZDF `Str` is not a `string::string` here.

Comment: @ZDF we can delete all comments concerning this `c_str() ` issue

Comment: It seems like this one is debugger issue. Only in debugger window that string does not show up. But when I use abc.GetBuffer, I am able to get "Stack Overflow" string.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not familiar with CString (mostly developing on unix / linux environment) but referring to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174288.aspx), I would use CStringW to store a wchar_t string.

But I thing your initialisation of your CString is wrong. According to the MSDN doc, I would rather do something like:

```
CStringW abc = _T(L"Stack Overflow");
```

Otherwise I would recommend to use wcstombs from the cstdlib to convert a wchar_t* to a char *  and stick to the standard.

See [wcstombs documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/wcstombs/).

Comment: Unicode is enabled in my project, so internally CString converts it into CStringW.

Comment: Nothing in the MSDN would ever recommend to do `CStringW abc = _T(L"Stack Overflow");`. That's just plain wrong. You use the explicit template instantiation for wide character strings (`CStringW`), and then feed it something, that tries to use the generic-text mappings. And fails to compile if Unicode is enabled. There's also no need to perform any conversions: The `CStringT` class template offers conversion constructors. I'm afraid, this is not helpful.

Comment: Strange; I read this in MSDN about using Unicode in MFC application, thus guided my answer: 

`To complete Unicode programming of your application, you must also:
    Use the _T macro to conditionally code literal strings to be portable to Unicode. `

see [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ey142t48.aspx)

Comment: That link never states that you should apply the `_T` macro to a **wide** character string literal. And really, the generic-text mappings were relevant 2 decades ago. You are invited to forget about those. Today, there is no supported version of Windows, that doesn't use UTF-16 as its internal character encoding format.